# PHP MySQLi - Display Product Based On Product Category

Tags: php, mysqli

I have around 5 meal category, for example 'M01' ('M' stands for Meal), 'B01' ('B' stands for Baverages) and so on. In every category page on front end, instead of showing everything in 1 page, I want to sort the product based on its category, for example in Baverages page, there will be a list of baverages under 'B01' category code. How can I achieve that with PHP and MySQLi? Sorry for the simple code, I'm still new to this. Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
<table  class="table-list">
    <tbody id="mealTable">
       <?php
          $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM meal");
          $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
          if ($row_count == 0) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td colspan = "6">
                <?php echo "No data found"; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php } else {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?> 
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['meal_name']?></td>
            <td>RM <?php echo $row['meal_price']?></td>
            <td ><a href="addtocart.php?mid=<?php echo $row['meal_id']; ?>"  style="background-color: green;  color: white; padding: 10px 10px;   text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;font-size: 14px; width: 70px; height: 13px; ">Add To Cart</a> 
            </td>
          </tr>
  <?php } }
  ?>
</div>
```

This is the List of Meal page on Admin side
[image]

This is the database table for Meal Category
[image]

This is the database table for Meal
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The code above is displaying all types of meal in 1 page. I have no idea how to separate them in different pages by using category.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `WHERE` to your query and use URL parameters?